# PHP Regex pattern for C???-??-?-*

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to match a string to this pattern C???-??-?-* 
(example: **CRPN-NN-N-036+**)

So far I found this regex pattern:

`/^(C-)*[a-zA-Z]{3}-[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]-`

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What does the `?` stand for?

Answer (score 3):

`^C[a-zA-Z]{3}-[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]-.*`

Here's [an example](http://regexr.com/3e571)

Comment: No, you were close! Glad you got it working,  happy coding =)

Answer (score 1):

The dot (.) matches a single character, without caring what that character is. The only exception are line break characters.

So, we can use ^C.{3}-.{2}-.-.* to make the regex more general. This pattern even can match C???-??-?-*